# Why always fail for the first read ID Tag on Zebra ZT411 RFID

Tags: c#, zebra-printers, zpl

I have Zebra ZT411 models and im using ZPL combined C# to get the ID Tag, but i don't know why its alway fail for the first tag. Sometime it response null, sometime it response serial number of ZT411. Always the first tag and all the next is fine. Im using USB connector and this is my code and ZPL command

```
string zplData = "^XA^RFR,H,2,6,1^FN1^FS^HV1,,^FS^XZ";

byte[] encodeData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(zplData);
received = connection.SendAndWaitForResponse(encodeData, 960, 650, "null");
if (received != null)
{
   string response2string = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received);
}
```

[first read and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4atm.png)

[the second read and real ID response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMZAw.png)

So i dont know what im doing wrong in zpl command or c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a Zebra ZD500R printer.
I had problems running this command.
I increased the *initialResponseTimeout* in the command

```
byte[] SendAndWaitForResponse(byte[] dataToSend, int initialResponseTimeout, int responseCompletionTimeout, string terminator);
```

to 2500ms and no more problems.

```
byte[] received = connection.SendAndWaitForResponse(encodeData, 2500, 500, "null");
```